# How can I export SPSS custom tables to a specific Excel sheet without the SPSS?

Tags: spss

I want to put different custom tables to different sheets in Excel. I tried with OMS and OUTPUT EXPORT but that functions not do what I want. If somebody have idea I hope that will help me. :)

Comment: You might start with offering at least a little information. For example, you might want to let us know what it is you want, and why what you got is not what you want.

Comment: For example, I have created 4 custom tables and  I want to put them in 4 different sheets. OMS puts table in different Excele file, I don't know how to specify a sheet in OMS. OUTPUT EXPORT puts table and the command text in different sheets but I want to put only table without CTABLE command.

Answer (score 0):

[`OUTPUT EXPORT`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLVMB_21.0.0/com.ibm.spss.statistics.help/syn_output_export.htm?lang=en) has an `OPERATION` subcommand with options `CREATEFILE` / `CREATESHEET` / `MODIFYSHEET` from which you can route `CTABLES` to desired sheets in a target/new Excel file.

You'll need to organise your `OUTPUT` documents as you wish your sheets.

Exorting to Excel using `OMS` you can not route to a specific sheet only with `OUTPUT EXPORT` you can.

Answer (score 0):

OUTPUT EXPORT can write different sheets, but it doesn't give you much flexibiity in the objects that get exported when using it via syntax.  The syntax mode assumes that you are not going to be interactively selecting the tables.

However, the SPSSINC OUTPUT MODIFY extension command includes a customoutputfunctions.py module that has an excelexport function that will do what you want.  Here is an example.  For more information see the SPSSINC OUTPUT MODIFY documentation or the dialog (on Utilities once installed).  Then look at the examples in the customoutputfunctions.py module.

SPSSINC MODIFY OUTPUT TABLES
/IF SUBTYPE="'Custom Table'" PROCESS=ALL
/CUSTOM FUNCTION="customoutputfunctions.excelexport(file='c:/temp/extest.xls',
  sheet='table#',action='CreateWorksheet')".